# start Splash screen activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to write a code that uses the splash screen .I have written this so far, but Can anyone tell me what is the missing here!?

here is my main code:

```
package com.example.splash;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }



}
```

and here is my splash activity code:

```
package com.example.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splashscreen extends Activity {

protected int _splashTime = 5000; 

    private Thread splashTread;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splashh);
             final splashscreen sPlashScreen = this; 

                splashTread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {                   
                            synchronized(this){
                                wait(_splashTime);
                            }

                        } catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
                        finally {
                            finish();

                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.setClass(sPlashScreen,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                            //stop();
                        }
                    }
                };


                splashTread.start();

    }
```

The problem is I do not know how to tell my main to go splash activity , if I use an intent I would stuck on infinite loop.

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/2345913)

Comment: Which is your first activity?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use this:

```
 Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {               
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashViewController.this,HomeViewController.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashViewController.this.finish();                         
            }
        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead :

```
public class splashscreen extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            Thread t = new Thread(Splash_Runnable);
            t.start();

        }





        Runnable Splash_Runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                        startActivity(new Intent(splashscreen.this,
                                MainActivity.class));
                        splashscreen.this.finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem (i guess) is that your app is starting with your `MainActivity` as your launcher Activity. Make `splashscreen` your laucher Activity in your Application Manifest XML and you will avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
private boolean _active = true;
private int _splashTime = 5000;

Thread splashTread = new Thread() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) 
                    {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active) 
                        {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                finally 
                {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
```

in `AndroidManifest` mention your activity as Main Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your SplashActivity code from here.

[Splash and main activity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008863/splash-and-main-activity-error/16008942#16008942)

Also make your splashactivtiy as your launcher activity and then redirect to the MainActivity from the SplashScreen

```
<activity
            android:name="com.app.wablogic.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full detail of creating a splash Activity

Create a layout for **Splash**

splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Now create a class Under package . Name it **Splash**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
            finish();

        }
    }, 5000);  //it will call the MainActivity after 5 seconds  
}
```

Go to `manifest` and add the `Activity` to it.

and cut the `intent-filter` where main and Launcher are child and paste it in **Splash** Activity like

```
 <activity
         android:name="com.example.yourpackage.Splash"
         android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Thread for doing something or just sleep for a few seconds to do, such as

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 3 seconds
                sleep(3*1000);

                // After 3 seconds redirect to another intent
                Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Remove activity
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    background.start();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

You can get more example [here](http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135).